# Using vtk module crashes Blender

Tags: python

I install vtk with homebrew (brew install vtk --with-python3 --without-python) on my MacOSX system.
Now I go in the Terminal shell, I start `python3`. Then I write `import vtk` and it works.

For the record, this is the python version installed with homebrew.

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Apr 18 2016, 03:49:24)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
```

And this is the one shipped with Blender 2.77a

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.5.1 (default, Feb  1 2016, 13:40:14)  
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

So I'm confident this will behave the same in Blender. 
I launch it, go in the console and write the following:

`import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/Cellar/vtk/7.0.0_2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/')
import vtk`

**And that's a guaranteed crash**

This isn't the first library I try to use which crashes at import time even if it works just fine in any other python environment. I doubt there's an easy solution (don't mention recompiling please). At least people reading this will know there's a problem and won't waste too much time on it...

Comment: Try copying `/usr/local/Cellar/vtk/7.0.0_2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` to `blender-2.77a/2.77/python/lib/python3.5/`.

Comment: I did that already, same behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success with this method:

I'm using Blender 2.78 with python 3.5. And I installed latest vtk through homebrew.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/vtk/7.1.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages")
import vtk
```

No problem, and https://github.com/cwant/VTKBlender module has been updated, so you might want to check that out

Answer (score 0):

I tried numerous method from compiling from source the vtk library to using brew. the version on python installed with brew was not the same than the one of blender and then importing vtk module in blender made blender crash every time. Apparently it was a conflict with the version of numpy of blender and my python(3.5.4 at the time)

I gave it a try one last time today. I decided to start from fresh. So I remove all my previous installation of python and etc... (ports alll...) and i just install vtk using brew:

```
brew install vtk --with-python3 --without-python
```

Then in the blender's console:

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/vtk/7.1.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages")
 import vtk
 from vtk.utils import tomato
```

It worked. 
So Nicolas maybe you should also give it a try.